# When building in Unity, is there a way to shorten build time other than "Scripts Only Build"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As other Unity developers know, the build time for a project increases drastically as the project grows. I know that Unity has added a "Scripts Only Build" option for development builds and I've seen the [Visual Studio Tools for Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/visual-studio-tools-for-unity), but I haven't found a way to reorganize the Unity project into Visual Studio projects.

Are there other ways to shorten the build time, like setting Unity to only build changed files or organizing a Unity project similar to Visual Studio solutions, where I can build individual projects as needed instead of the entire solution?

Comment: Using Unity 2018.2 and Visual Studio 2017

Comment: do you use baked lightmaps? thats what it takes more time, if you don't then uncheck "autogenerate" lighting (window->lighting) in all your scenes and thats it, ultra fast builds.

Comment: could it be that VisualStudio is slowing it down?  Just change to SI3.  You can't "chop up" the project, no.   I do not find builds to be long, even with very large projects FWIW.

Comment: @Lestat, we did have auto generate checked on some scenes, so that definitely is contributing to our build times.